# Use conditional to hide or show entry

Tags: relationships, conditionals

I would like to use a conditional to hide or show information from an entry. The following code is pulling in data from an EE relationship field. If there is no entry I would like this code NOT to show. I have tried to use {if}{/if} statements, but cannot work the code out!

```
<h4>{manufacturer_profile:title}</h4>   
<p>{manufacturer_profile:manufacturer_summary}</p>
```

Would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Reading th docs, if there is no relationship your code shouldn't  show. What EE version are u using ?

Comment: @stuartmcd69 I'm using the latest full version of EE.

Comment: @stuartmcd69 I am using this code and it works: 
{if "{manufacturer_profile:count}" == ""}
{if:else}
<h4>{manufacturer_profile:title}</h4> 
<p>{manufacturer_profile:manufacturer_summary}</p>
{/if}
Just wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Change {if "{manufacturer_profile:count}" == ""}  to {if "{manufacturer_profile:count}" != ""} and leave off the {if:else}

Comment: @JohnathanWaters Thank you so much, so easy now. That worked just as I wanted.

Comment: Glad we could help. You should post an answer and mark this question as complete

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable pair:

```
{manufacturer_profile}
    <h4>{manufacturer_profile:title}</h4>   
    <p>{manufacturer_profile:manufacturer_summary}</p>
{/manufacturer_profile}
```